# Is there something I can do to optimise my linq query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have to be able to sort out a list of object which might contains doubloon with certain criteria. So far the code is working but it takes 10 minutes for 50,000 rows in my list.

Here is the code :

```
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string value1;
        public string value2;
        public string value3;
        public string value4;

        public int num1;
        public int num2;
    }

    public static List<TestObject> ReturnTestObjectListWithoutDoubloon(List<TestObject> source)
    {
        var destination = new List<TestObject>();
        var list = new Dictionary<int, TestObject>();


        while (source.Count > 0)
        {
            list.Clear();
            var originalElement = source[0];

            foreach (var query in source.Select((element, index) => new { Value = element, Index = index })
            .Where(currentElement => (currentElement.Value.value1 == originalElement.value1)
                                    && (currentElement.Value.value2 == originalElement.value2)
                                    && (currentElement.Value.value3 == originalElement.value3)
                                    && (currentElement.Value.value4 == originalElement.value4)))
            {
                list.Add(query.Index, query.Value);
            }

            if (list.Count > 1)
            {
                originalElement.num1 = list.Sum(a => a.Value.num1);
                originalElement.num2 = list.Sum(a => a.Value.num2);
            }

            destination.Add(originalElement);
            foreach (var positionToremove in list.Keys)
                source.RemoveAt(positionToremove);
        }

        return destination;
    }
```

The idea is to reduce the list each time I pass the while loop so my Linq request is executed on the smallest list possible. However the fewer doubloons I have , the slower it is. I am looking for a solution which allows me to have the smallest rutnime possible, memory is not an issue.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: doubloon = double elements and you want to do something when you encounter that case?

Comment: I smell a copypasta error : are you sure about comparing value3 to value4? (currentElement.Value.value3 == originalElement.value4)

Comment: A doubloon is a gold coin. I don't see what that has to do with this problem.

Comment: @Florian Doyon - Yes it is. I fixed it now thanks.  @Gabe - Me too. It's just that my english isn't that good. @Femaref - Yes.

Comment: the correct word in this case would be "duplicate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to follow your code through - and it looks like you are simply looking to remove duplicates from your source list?

If that is the case:

- then I think your `source.RemoveAt` code might be broken as it might remove the wrong elements.
- then you should be able to run a single GroupBy() operation on this source list - that should work using a hashtable which should be much quicker than your existing loops-inside-loops operation.

  ```
  var query = from s in source
              group s by new {
                  value1 = s.value1,
                  value2 = s.value2,
                  value3 = s.value3,
                  value4 = s.value4
              } into grouped
              select new TestObject()
              {
                  value1 = grouped.Key.value1,
                  value2 = grouped.Key.value2,
                  value3 = grouped.Key.value3,
                  value4 = grouped.Key.value4,
                  num1 = grouped.Sum(x => x.num1),
                  num2 = grouped.Sum(x => x.num2)
              };
  return query.ToList();
  ```

Comment: `Distinct` won't work due to the added requirement of aggregating results.

Comment: Agreed - I'd worked that out and was off changing the answer - but too late... you've beaten me to it! I'll upvote yours...

Comment: Since I store indexes of my source that I got from the query, I am sure that every index is the right one.I tested my code on smaller lists it went fine. I might have made a mistake in the pasting though. Can you please tell me which part is the matter ? I will try this, thank you !

Comment: I think the problem is if you start with items A,B,C,D and you want to delete item at positions 1 and 3 (A, C) - then first you delete position 1 which is A and that leaves you with B,C,D; then you delete position 3 - which now is D - which is *wrong* :( To correct this behaviour you could simply delete them in reverse order.

Comment: You are right, I didn't include the reverse when positing here. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, you have multiple elements with the same key and want to do something in that case. simply use a group by statement:

```
source.GroupBy(s => new
                    {
                      Value1 = s.Value1,
                      Value2 = s.Value2,
                      Value3 = s.Value3,
                      Value4 = s.value4
                    })
      .Select(g => new TestObject
                   {
                      Value1 = g.Key.Value1,
                      Value2 = g.Key.Value2,
                      Value3 = g.Key.Value3,
                      Value4 = g.Key.value4,
                      Num1 = g.Sum(s => s.Num1),
                      Num2 = g.Sum(s => s.Num2)
                   });
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a difference in your opinion, in terms of performance between your code and @Stuart. I'm asking because I never really got the difference between calling the operator from IEnumerable objects or using Linq syntax. I hope I made myself clear O_o

Comment: no, there is no difference at all - Stuart's code is just a way to write my code in a more sql like syntax (it actually should translate to exactly my code). The query syntax is a way to express complex queries in a more readable way, however it can use all features possible in LINQ.

Comment: Ok so it really is a matter of taste. Thank you.

Comment: mostly, yes. but as I said, not all queries can be expressed with the query syntax.